# Find the maximum depth of a set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, intervals, greedy

Given a set of intervals I, each element of the form [a_i, b_i], find an end point b_i of maximum depth in **O(n*logn)** time. Define depth of x as the number of intervals the point "stabs" (or intersects). If two end point have the same depth, return the smaller one.

---

Attempt:

I have no idea how to find it in O(n * logn) time. I understand the greedy algorithm for finding the stabbing set of a set of intervals, but finding an end point with strictly O(n * log n) time seems very different.

I can try and first sort the intervals and brute force a maximum depth end point but that does not guarantee O(n * log n) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

- sort your points a_i and b_i (together in one array)
- traversing the sorted array increase a counter (depth) when you encounter an "a" point (starting an interval) and decreases it for "b" point (end of an interval) - here you can find your "b" point with maximum depth

Comment: Correct, but you have to be careful to to sort an "a" before a "b" if they have the same value. For example: [0, 1], [1, 2] -- the maximum depth is 2, which means you have to sort the numbers as [a0, a1, b1, b2] and not [a0, b1, a1, b2].

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can maintain a vector<pair<int, int>> data while taking the intervals as input. Just push the starting point as make_pair(start_point,0), 0 to identify the starting point, and similarly, 1 for the end of the interval.
Now do the following:-

1. Sort the entire vector in increasing order according to the first index
2. Now traverse the vector from the beginning and initialise variables iter=0, vector<pair<int, int>> a={make_pair(0,-inf)} -> to store max_depth and the corresponding endpoint.
3. Do iter++ if the second index is 0; otherwise if it is 1, do iter--.
4. While you do iter++, check if(a[0].first<iter) then do a[0].first=iter && a[0].second=-inf;
5. While doing iter--, check if(iter == a[0].first) then if(a[0].second< data[0].first) then a[0].second=data[i].first;
6. After traversing the whole vector in this fashion, a[0].first is the maximum depth, and a[0].second is the end point corresponding to the maximum_depth.

Comment: This is clearer than the previous answer as in the previous answer; it is not clear how to traverse and store the endpoint as per the requirement of the question.